# Как можно сделать имплементацию интерфейса обязательной?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

У меня есть класс который наследует от `FragmentDialog` и общается с активити через интерфейс.

Но проблема в том, что когда создаешь обьект класса диалога, то нужно бы не забыть имплементировать интерфейс, а то потом когда диалог попробует вызвать метод на интерфейсе то приложение поломается...

Понятно, что можно когда все написал протестировать и посмотреть, чтоб все работало... Но я думаю может можно как то сделать его обязательным?

Comment: кто должен имплементировать интерфейс? Activity?

Comment: вы пишите, не запуская? а почему?

Comment: @metalurgus да активити

Comment: @YuraIvanov где я пишу не запуская?

Comment: Смотрите первый вариант в ответе @P.llyin. Я бы сделал так. Если надо подробнее объяснить, попросите его, или меня.

Comment: Как реализованно получение экземпляра листенера?

Comment: @metalurgus да можете пожалуйста обьяснить как правильно это реализовать в андроид?

Comment: @temq в смысле интерфейса? Присваиваю его в `onAttach()`...

Comment: Ну тогда делайте так, как предлагает гугл, т.е. проверять контекст который в аттаче на принадлежность его к данному интерфейсу, и кидайте исключение если он его не реализует, по другому никак не обяжешь.

Comment: @temq ну вот это и есть вопрос) Думал может как то делают...

Answer (score 2):

1. Если интерфейсы из одного метода, да еще и из одного аргумента, да еще и стримы в проекте, то можно заменить их консамерами и объявлять их в классе сразу с пустым телом, чтобы приложение не падало.

   ```
   public class A {
     private Consumer<String> mSomeStringListener = val -> {};
   }
   ```
2. Заприватить конструкторы класса и разрешить создавать экземпляры только специальным билдером, который будет навязывать пользователю сеттеры для интерфейсов
3. Создать конструктор со всеми необходимыми интферфейсами, чтобы точно ничего не забыть

Comment: Консьюмеры на андроиде? Его уже портнули на Java 8?

Comment: Нет, но у нас на работе на всех проектах ретролямда и стримы, так что я настолько привык к этим плюшкам, что забываю каждый раз в своих ответах добавлять что-то типа "если есть стримы, то..."

Comment: @Nofate https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html?hl=ru

Comment: @KirillStoianov, Android **N Preview** SDK.

Comment: Так я так и не понял насчет того есть ли это уже на андроиде?

Comment: Почему плюсуют неверный ответ? 1. Как это поможет обязать activity имплементить интерфейс и не слишком ли много ограничений на интерфейс (один метод, один аргумент, стримы...)? 2 и 3. К такому `android.support.v4.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment 
make sure class name exists, is public, and has an empty constructor that is public` готовы?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста подробнее обьяснить ваш ответ?

Answer (score -2):

Может передать предмет в `newInstance`?

```
public class NewDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private Interface privateInterface;

    public static NewDialogFragment newInstance(Interface i){
        NewDialogFragment frag = new NewDialogFragment();
        frag.privateInterface = i;
        return frag;
    }

    public NewDialogFragment(){

    }

}
```

Comment: `FragmentDialog` требует использовать дефолтный конструктор, а все что необходимо передавать в `Bandle`

Comment: Согласен, неправильное решение. Изменю ответ.

Comment: Да, но как тогда закрыть доступ к дефолтным конструкторам?

Comment: Сделать конструктор private не рекомендуется... Можно попробовать чтобы `Interface` имплементировал `Serializable` и передать его в `Bandle`.

Comment: Еще можно свойство `privateInterface` сделать  `@NonNull` но мне кажется что это не решит проблемы.

Comment: @AlexVorobiev, как вы себе представляете сериализированый объект интерфейса? Как по вашему ссылка на объект сохранится?

Comment: Верно, не сохраниться. Oтошел от проблемы. Думал как сохранить объект так как `Activity` нужен дефолтный конструктор `DialogFragment`'a.